# Searching for string (needle) in an array of comma separated words (haystack)

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I know this seems like a crazy question but I cannot figure out the best solution for the following situation.

I have an array of 'categories' and each of those have a string of 'searches'. Those searches are a string of commas separated words that works as a `strpos` to match a category.

Example of the category array

```
$categories = [
  0 => [
    'category' => 'Foo',
    'searches' => 'fet,cre,oho'
  ],
  1 => [
    'category' => 'Bar',
    'searches' => 'lois,vreb,mon'
  ],
]
```

Here is the issue. Say I have the word `secret`. As you can see, the first array in `$categories` has `searches` that contain `cre` in the string. The problem I am having is the approach to giving a string (in this exmaple 'secret') a category based on the given string having a `strpos()` in one of the words separated by the commas in searches then return the category (Can only have one cat).

Outcome I am looking for:

```
function findCategory($string)
{
  $category = false;

  // code to take the string,
  // look through $categories
  // find the first occurrence of a string position
  // in the comma separated list of possible matches

  return $category ? $category : 'Other';
}

echo findCategory('secret'); // Foo
echo findCategory('monster'); // Bar
echo findCategory('cohort'); // Foo
echo findCategory('tense'); // Other
```

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: The question is a little Broad, have you not tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Best I can think of id loop through all the categories and searches in each category, then treat each search as a regex pattern and match it against the original string. If there is a match assign the category.

Comment: From your question, you have the approach. You just have to write the code for it. Once you have an actual issue with trying to code it, come back to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure GrumpyCruton's answer is quite going to work as the in_array() method will require a full match not a partial match as you require. Perhaps something like the following will work for you:

```
function findCategory($needle, $categories) {
  foreach($categories as $category){
    $searches = explode($delimiter, $category['searches']);
    foreach ($searches as $search){
      if(strpos($needle, $search) !== false){
        return $category['category'];
      }
    }
  }
  return 'Other';
}
```

I haven't actually tested this but I think that should get you on the right track.

Comment: If you pander to the "Do it for me, Crowd" they just keep coming back for more

Comment: @RiggsFolly If people want to help let them help. More then 90% of the time I divert to solving it myself, but I've been fighting with this for the whole day. I wanted a starting point. Goodness..

Comment: @RiggsFolly Probably, but if I help someone get to their solution then I don't care. Although, I probably should have commented it more for educational purposes.

Comment: But the SO community care. They want good quality searchable question on programming problems, that also have good quality answers.

Comment: As you can see from my profile I'm new to answering questions on here so I will endeavour to produce better quality answers with more commenting in the future.
Although, your original criticism was that I just told the guy how to do it rather than making him do it himself and I don't see how not fully answering his question would help create "good quality searchable questions", perhaps you can give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then this function should help you.

```
function findCategory($needle, $categories, $delim = ",") {
    //loop through every category
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        //split searches string into an array of strings
        $searches = explode($delim, $category['searches']);
        //if needle exists in array of strings, return category.
        if(in_array($needle, $searches)) return $category['category'];
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
findCategory($needle, $categories);
```

Optionally you can pass a 3rd param as the delimiter between the words in `searches`

Comment: You should let the OP try before writing the answer, shouldn't you ?

Comment: @ksjohn Upon another read I don't think this actually helps OP anyways. But either way I always heavily comment my answers so that they can help OP learn how to do it

Comment: You are correct, it does not, but the approach will be similar

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Another read for myself, and I guess you're right

Answer (score 0):

```
function findCategory($word) {
    global $categories;
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        $subarray = explode(',', $val['searches']);
        foreach ($subarray as $str) {
            if (strpos($word, $str) !== false) {
                return ($val['category']);
            }
        }
    }
    return 'Other';
}
```

My function get the array with the categories with a `global`, you can include it in the function itself if you want, same thing.
It iterates through the array, then through the explode of the current `['searches']` and try to find the current piece of word in the word you pass as an argument, returning the corresponding category's name if it succeeds. If the function tries every piece of string without success, 'Other' is returned instead.

Comment: Dammit, I deleted when I saw that the OP seemingly hadn't tried to solve her/his problem until more code was shown, but it looks like a vain battle. I might as well undelete it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this function :

```
<?php

$categories = [
  ['category' => 'Foo', 'searches' => 'fet,cre,oho'],
  ['category' => 'Bar', 'searches' => 'lois,vreb,mon'],
];

function findCategory($string, $categories)
{
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        foreach(explode(',', $category['searches']) as $search) {
            if (false !== strpos($string, $search)) {
               return $category['category'];
            }
        }
    }

  return 'Other';
}

echo findCategory('secret', $categories) . '<br>';
echo findCategory('monster', $categories) .  '<br>';
echo findCategory('cohort', $categories) . '<br>';
echo findCategory('tense', $categories) . '<br>';
```

**output:**

```
Foo
Bar
Foo
Other
```

Comment: If you pander to the "Do it for me, Crowd" they just keep coming back for more